# Problema con rutas de archivo - java -

Tags: java

Hola en mi aplicación debes elegir una carpeta con JfileChooser y que se cree un archivo de texto dentro de ella.Con este codigo no me funciona.He puesto un ejemplo de una ruta correcta, que luego la imprima y luego en el jfilechooser al elegir la misma ruta  me da error y sin embargo a la hora de imprimirse veo que son iguales si uso el jfilechooser no me funciona.Creo que el error esta en la uri del`new file`.

codigo:

```
    public void escribirarchivo() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    int respuesta = fc.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (respuesta == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        File archivoElegido = fc.getSelectedFile();

        //aqui es donde,si lo cambio por la ruta especifica me funciona, si no, me da error
        File file = new File(archivoElegido.toURI() + "file.txt");

        //aqui es donde lo imprimo y son iguales
        System.out.println(archivoElegido.toURI() + "file.txt");           


        System.out,println(archivoElegido.toURI() + ""file:/C:/Users/Alonso/Desktop/ejemplotxt/file.txt"")

        if (!file.exists()) {
        try {

            file.createNewFile();
            System.out.println(file.getName() + " Ha sido creado");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("error");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `toURI()` regresa un objeto tipo `URI`, el cual al ser convertido internamente dentro del println muestra realmente `toURI().toString()`, dicha conversión no es igualmente automática en el constructor de `File`. Por lo que deberías invocar adicionalmente `toString()` o simplemente usar `archivoElegido.getPath()` que devuelve un String que puedes concatenar sin problema con `"file.txt"`. String + String = String. URI + String = ?.